# gwmi win32_service -ComputerName IP –credential userName returns Access denied but Enter-PSSession -ComputerName IP -Credential Personal works

Tags: powershell-5.0

Running this powershell command

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName 192.168.1.184 -Credential Personal
```

command works fine. The username and password is accepted.
Again, running this command:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 192.168.1.184 -ScriptBlock { Get-ChildItem C:\ } -credential Personal
```

Also works fine and it displays the folders in drive C. It also implies that i can login. When i run this command:

```
gwmi win32_service –credential Personal –computer 192.168.1.184
```

*I get "gwmi : Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))"*

So does this:

```
Copy-Item -Path c:\d\test.txt -Destination \\192.168.1.184\c$\dep\test.txt
```

I've tried everything i could think of and i still fail. My goal is to copy files to target computers and execute these files. I have about 52 machines and i need to be able to install these programs.
Anyone knows why this isn't working?

Comment: Just to clarify, the computer/laptops are not in a domain. They all belong to the workgroup.